# How to use a button to come back to the index, checking the pagination table of a specific ID?

Tags: javascript, html, yii2, back

I have this problem: I use Yii2 and, when I go to an index page, I select a view for an element (Example, I go to the page 4, because I want to enter in the view of the element with ID 41, which is at the page 4 because I have the pagination set to 10). This is ok for me but, when I enter in the view, I have this link to come back to the index:

```
<?= Html::a ( "Back", ['codici/index/','CodiciSearch[IDCodice]='=>$model['IDCodice']], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Actually, this return to the index, but it show me only the record with the ID that I pass to the link. So, in this case, only the record 41. I want, instead, that the Back button turn to the previous page checking the pagination in which I was, and not only the ID. So, the link must checking the pagination of an ID. I hope to be clear. I don't need a solution like "window.history.go(-1)" because this create a problem if I came to the view by another way. I would to have a specific option: the link must to return to the index and get the pagination of an ID (so, in this ex. case, to the page 4).
I hope to be clear. Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the solutions I use:

1. most times I just open the target page in a new tab. That is the simplest solution. If this is acceptable then simply add a parameter to the Html::a options as follows:

   Html::a(“text”,[url],[‘target’=>’_blank’]);

Note: if the link is within a Gridview you need to set the format to raw (“format”=>”raw”)

2. on the index page, pass the pagination number to the new page.

   Html::a(“text”,[url, ‘index_pagination’=>5]);

You can then use this in your button

3. instead of passing the pagination, you can capture the referring page and send the user back:

   $url = Yii::$app->request->referrer

This is easy but it can cause challenges if the user reloads the page in which case the referring page is the current page.